# python LoadLibrary error No such file or directory

Tags: python, ctypes, loadlibrary

my code:

```
import ctypes
import os

path = '/home/sprite/code/lib/linux/libhcnetsdk.so'

if os.path.exists(path):
    lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(path)
```

Error:

> OSError: /home/sprite/code/lib/linux/libhcnetsdk.so: cannot open
> shared object file: No such file or directory

how can i fix this?

Comment: Maybe the error message is misleading, it might be unreadable or not loadable as SO for some other reason.